# If-else chain of range-checks not executing as expected

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements, relational-operators

When I pass certain float value to compare with my conditional statement it always executes else part.

There are some variables with values:

```
float total = 74.67 ; 
String grade = "", point = "";
```

And with this values I want to do this:

```
if(total>=80){
        grade = "A+";
        point = "4.00";
}else if(total<=79 && total>=75){
        grade = "A";
        point = "3.75";
}else if(total>=70 && total<=74) {
        grade = "A-";
        point = "3.50";
}else if(total<=65 && total>=69){
        grade = "B+";
        point = "3.25";
}else if(total<=64 && total>=60){
        grade = "B";
        point = "3.00";
}else if (total<=59 && total>=55){
        grade = "B-";
        point = "2.75";
}else if (total<=54 && total>=50){
        grade = "C+";
        point = "2.50";
}else if(total<=49 && total>=45){
        grade = "C";
        point = "2.25";
}else if (total<=44 && total>=40){
        grade = "D";
        point = "2.00";
}else {
        grade = "F";
        point = "0.00";
}
```

but it always shows grade  = "F" and point = "0.00".

if I write this,

```
if(total>=70 && total<=74) {
        grade = "A-";
        point = "3.50";
    }
```

it shows grade ="" and point ="".

> the value of total is showing nicely but there are problem with grade
>   and point. can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Why don't you try debugging it ?

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: do you think `74.67 <= 74`?

Comment: Like @ADM says, you need to learn to debug your app. See the details https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: The main problem with your code is you're comparing for int value not the float value. So, everytime you have a value between the comparison, e.g. 74 -> 75, it will always fall on the `else` part.

Comment: Yes your comparison is wrong try Sujan's answer

Comment: I suggest you rewrite all the conditions as per this example: `if (40 <= total && total <= 44)`, just as in mathematics. Then you will see which ones don't make sense. Writing them all any old way makes that impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking between 79-75 and then 70-74 but there is a part missing between 74-75

```java
...
else if(total<=79 && total>=75){ 
        grade = "A";
        point = "3.75";
    }else if(total>=70 && total<=74) {
        grade = "A-";
        point = "3.50";
    }
...
```

change the `java total>=70 && total<=74` to `java total>=70 && total<75` include from 70-less than 75

so  your final code will be

```java
if(total>=80){
        grade = "A+";
        point = "4.00";
    }else if(total<80 && total>=75){
        grade = "A";
        point = "3.75";
    }else if(total>=70 && total<75) {
        grade = "A-";
        point = "3.50";
    }else if(total>=65 && total<70){ // here was another mistake
        grade = "B+";
        point = "3.25";
    }else if(total<65 && total>=60){
        grade = "B";
        point = "3.00";
    }else if (total<60 && total>=55){
        grade = "B-";
        point = "2.75";
    }else if (total<55 && total>=50){
        grade = "C+";
        point = "2.50";
    }else if(total<50 && total>=45){
        grade = "C";
        point = "2.25";
    }else if (total<45 && total>=40){
        grade = "D";
        point = "2.00";
    }
    else {
        grade = "F";
        point = "0.00";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should have to try

If you want to print this value in "Grade A" Then try

```
if(total<80 && total>74){
    grade = "A";
    point = "3.75";
}else if(total>=70 && total<=74) {
    grade = "A-";
    point = "3.50";
}
```

or

If you want to print this value in "Grade A-" Then try

```
 if(total<80 && total>=75){
    grade = "A";
    point = "3.75";
}else if(total>=70 && total<75) {
    grade = "A-";
    point = "3.50";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the condition is getting satisfy here that's why it is executing else part.

> But this would happen with not only 74.67 but with many other values
>   as well your condition should be like this,

```
if(total>81){
        grade = "A+";
        point = "4.00";
    }else if(total<80 && total>76){
        grade = "A";
        point = "3.75";
    }else if(total>71 && total<75) {
        grade = "A-";
        point = "3.50";
    }else if(total>66 && total<70){ // here was another mistake
        grade = "B+";
        point = "3.25";
    }else if(total<65 && total>61){
        grade = "B";
        point = "3.00";
    }else if (total<60 && total>56){
        grade = "B-";
        point = "2.75";
    }else if (total<55 && total>51){
        grade = "C+";
        point = "2.50";
    }else if(total<50 && total>46){
        grade = "C";
        point = "2.25";
    }else if (total<45 && total>41){
        grade = "D";
        point = "2.00";
    } else {
        grade = "F";
        point = "0.00";
    }
```

> And here instead of if else you should use switch case, it would be
>   more optimized and will take less compile time